# 'child_process'.exec vs .spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process, spawn

I do understand the difference of concept between `.exec` and `.spawn`.
I am trying to run a simple command, lets say `echo`.

With .exec, the command does work as expected.
With .spawn I receive `Error: spawn echo ENOENT`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
// WORKS AS EXEPCTED
const exec= require('child_process').exec;
exec("echo hello", function(err, stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
});

// THROWS
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn("echo", ["hello"]); // fail
```

Error received :

```
Error: spawn echo ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I am running on Windows!

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Please provide your code sample, without which it is difficult to answer. There is no outstanding bug on neithr exec nor spawn on such basic command executions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find the answer to my question.
The problem is that the `spawn` implementation on Windows can only start executables.

To avoid this problem, you can use [win-spawn](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/win-spawn).